# Validação mensagem de Texto Python

Tags: python, validação

Alguém tem ideia de como eu faço para validar uma mensagem de texto no Python, eu tenho uma tela que quando clico em cadastrar e tiver alguma informação incorreta ele mostra uma mensagem de erro informando a inconsistência...

Por exemplo:

Existe uma pagina que preencho com dados válidos para efetivar um cadastro, quando todas as informações estão corretas o cadastro é feito corretamente, porém, quando tem algum campo com informação incorreta exibe uma mensagem de erro impressa na tela como por exemplo " CNPJ inválido" , eu gostaria de saber se consigo validar essa mensagem , eu estou utilizando o Python e o Katalon 
para automatizar alguns testes.

[image: Mensagem a ser validada]

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara; por favor, faça o [tour] para entender como a comunidade funciona, leia o guia de [ask] para verificar como pode melhorar sua pergunta e, principalmente, veja como elaborar um [mcve] para complementar a sua pergunta.

Comment: ok.. Acredito que agora esta mais clara

Comment: "falando de automação de teste", agora ficou mais confuso ainda. Que automação é essa que quer fazer?

Comment: Estou automatizando uma pagina da Web, e preciso de uma rotina que valide uma mensagem de texto ( conforme a imagem que mandei ).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o seguinte para renderizar seu form no template:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label_tag }}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

Com isto, será exibido o tipo de erro acima de cada campo, se o formato esta inválido ou se é uma informação duplicada por exemplo em caso de um Create ou UpdateView...